# Create sequence without end point

Tags: r, dataframe, seq

I would like to create a sequence with as many numbers as columns I use.

I know the `seq(from = 1, to = 100, by = 1)` function, but I want something like:

```
seq(from = 1, to = *"UNTIL LAST COLUMN"*, by = 1)
```

The reason is that I want to do this with several data frames and do not want to repeatedly type in the number of columns that they have (because they differ).

Comment: You can try `seq_len(ncol(df))`

Comment: Simply: `seq(myDF)`

Answer (score 3):

Well you can use `ncol` to determine the number of columns in your data.frame:

- Either use `seq(from = 1, to = ncol(df), by = 1)`
- Or even shorter `1:ncol(df)`
- Or faster: `seq_len(ncol(df))`
- Or `seq(df)`

Comment: glad I could help, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the green check-mark on the left.

Answer (score 2):

The solution by [@Cettt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59175513/12158757) covers almost everything you want. Besides, you can also use `seq_along(df)` to generate the sequence.

For example

```
> df <- data.frame(1:3,2:4,3:5)
> seq_along(df)
[1] 1 2 3
```